# What happened to Finn's blaster at Maz Kanata's?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

When entering, we see that Finn has the blaster that was given to him earlier:

[image: Entering Maz]

However, when the fighting begins, Finn tells Maz that he needs a weapon and no longer has his blaster with him.  It seems unlikely to have been lost in the first shots, given how it is secured across his body.  Also, Han and Chewie didn't lose their weapons and they are arguably less secure.

Now, when the team gets to the Resistance base, Finn again has his blaster:

[image: Resistance Base]

So where was this blaster during the battle?

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe he left it at the ship he was going to leave with, then forgot it when the attack started?

Comment: A deleted scene reveals the cinematic answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is explained in the film's [Junior novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(junior_novelization))

> *Finn glanced at the rubble that surrounded them. **He’d lost his blaster
>   in their escape from the castle.** “I need a weapon.”*

In the [Official novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novelization)), we also get a brief exchange that didn't appear in the film or the script:

> *He looked back the way they had come. “**Lost my blaster.** I need a
>   weapon.” Displaying surprising strength for one so small, Maz grabbed
>   the wrist holding the lightsaber and raised it up. “You have one!”*

---

As far as *how he got it back* (in time for the next scene at D'Qar), after the First Order troops left there was no pressure of time. It's likely that he simply made his way back into the rubble and found where he'd dropped it.

I think we can assume that the "*Finn spends ten minutes looking for the blaster he dropped because he's an idiot*" scene is going to be on the Blu-ray.

Comment: The last paragraph contradicts the script - he already HAD his blaster because he used it to fire at some Stormtroopers, right BEFORE they left with Kylo Ren. So he had no 15 minutes to search.

Comment: @DVK - That was a [generic stormtrooper blaster](http://i.stack.imgur.com/P7toA.png). He picked it up off a dead trooper two cuts before.

Comment: Wut? I can swear I saw this comment 2 hours ago. SE is acting strange

Comment: BTW, worth including script quote from my deleted-answer anyways, it seems highly related even if doesn't 100% answer things.

Comment: @DVK - I reposted the comment since the earlier version didn't have the clicky-link

Answer (score -3):

Could Han or the previous owners have had more of the same type blaster stockpiled and left in the Falcon? I know the Falcon had about 3 or so different owners since it was taken from Han, but a weapon stash was apparently still onboard, as Han didn't have time to take a bunch of weapons from the large cargo ship he and Chewie were working out of when the gangs chased them away on The Falcon. Perhaps Finn was able to find the gun in the basement rubble right before they left Takodana or Han simply had another just like on the Falcon. How Finn first lost the weapon is what I can't figure out, I know there was supposedly a deleted scene of Maz using the force to pull down a ceiling on some troopers, and perhaps around that time in a skirmish Finn somehow dropped his weapon or was disarmed of it?

Comment: This sounds like pure speculation.

Comment: Pablo Hidalogo Lucasfilm storygroup head said they are standard Resistance blasters. They had been using them for a while.